# How do I get a complex return value from a Main() in C#

Tags: c#, return, exe

exe file written in C# 
which i need to return a complex return value to another C# project

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    private class MyObject
    {
        private int num;

        public int Num
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.num);
            }
            set
            {
                this.num = value;
            }
        }

        public MyObject(int num)
        {
            this.Num = num;
        }

    }

    [STAThread]
    public static MyObject Main(string[] args)
    {
        return new MyObject(5);
    }
}
```

this gives me the following error:
...\ConsoleApplication1.exe' 
does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.

I've tried playing with it but i got no success in making it return a complex value.

Comment: Why do you need that? There are many ways to send objects between programs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this from a `Main` method which is meant to be the entry point of the process.

If you're writing code to be called directly from other code, you should almost certainly be building a Class Library project instead. You *can* add a reference from one application to another, but it's unusual (at least outside unit tests). If you want to do this, you should just call a different method instead of `Main`. (You *could* have a `Main` method declared that way in one class, and use a different class as the "normal" entry point, but that seems pointlessly complicated.)

Comment: How can i get a return value from an .exe other then writing a return in main?
If i call another function it will simply return it's value to main
I need the main to return the value to C# code i have...

Comment: @KostyaSydoruk the return from main has been traditionally used to simply indicate if a program exited normally. If you need more complex information than that, consider writing the "output" of a program to a file. Or use a library-to-library call (as Jon explained), or use inter-process communication (e.g. wcf). But the return from main is a rather simplistic bit of information and not what you are looking for.

Comment: @KostyaSydoruk: You can use some sort of interprocess communication methods (sockets, pipe, stdin/stdout, etc.), or use the file system to communicate your return value.

Comment: @LMC +1 for directing to lower level principles (i.e. sockets, pipes, stdin/stdout). I opted to mention WCF for its object oriented api given the OP's example.

Comment: @KostyaSydoruk: Note also that a class library does not have a Main method. It defines types and methods that you can use in other applications, but is not running like an application. However, if you have to get some information from another **running** application, a return value whatsoever will not help you. In that case you will need some sort of interprocess communication (as LMC said).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, if you are invoking your exe as a standalone executable, then `Main` has to run and all you get is traditional process inputs/outputs.

But you can reference an exe as a library, too, if you really need to.

If this is the code for your exe:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private int num;

    public int Num
    {
        get
        {
           return (this.num);
        }
        set
        {
           this.num = value;
        }
    }

    public MyObject(int num)
    {
        this.Num = num;
    }    
}

public class Program
{
    public static MyObject DoWork(int num)
    {
        return new MyObject(num);
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoWork(5);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

From another exe or dll (assuming you have referenced your first exe) you can invoke the code like this:

```
MyObject obj = Program.DoWork(8)
```

This is a very unusual approach, though.  If you have libraries which define rich classes/methods that you need in multiple places, you should really put them in a dll.